# How to send html in document.write() in ajax function?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I've recently started using Ajax and javascript.

This is my ajax function:

```
   var saveForm = function () {
var form = $(this);
$.ajax({
  url: form.attr("action"),
  data: form.serialize(),
  type: form.attr("method"),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    if (data.form_is_valid) {

      w=window.open();
      w.document.write($("#book-table tbody").html(data.html_book_list));
      w.print();
      w.close();

      $("#book-table tbody").html(data.html_book_list);

      $("#modal-book").modal("hide");

    }
    else {
      $("#modal-book .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
    }
  }
});
return false;
};
```

In the output it only displays `[object Object]` and no html is getting passed.

How can I pass correct html to the document.write() and how can I access the "data" to perform modification?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do the same thing twice ... `$('#abc').html()` should dump the desired code into the target element (#abc) -- try just passing `data.html_book_list` instead of the jQuery part ... `w.document.write(data.html_book_list);` (assuming that the data returned has .html_book_list)

Comment: Then try ... `w.document.write( $("#book-table tbody").html() );` -- by passing an argument to `.html()` jQuery wants to write the data; but without an argument it should return the contents of the selection.

Comment: It worked!!. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to modify that html?

Comment: Sure, you will need to assign it to your target first (as you're doing later down in the code).  You can create a function to clean/format the data that comes in and then dump it to '#book-table tbody' -- after that repeat the step you already have

Comment: We'd have to see what the data looks like as it comes back, but your code could look something like: `var content = cleanData( data.html_book_list );` `$("#book-table tbody").html(content);` `w=window.open();` ... and continue as you have (removing the `.html()` assignment to "#book-table tbody", since you already did it) In this example the `function cleanData(info)` will need to be created to mutate the data how you would prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#element').html()` returns a string of the content that exists at the target.

`$('#element').html('some html')` returns the HTML object that has the new code added to it.

```js
$('#output').html( $('#test').html() );

// returns a string of the HTML inside
console.log( $('#test3').html() );
// returns the object being targeted
console.log( $('#test2').html('some html') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>

<div id="test">Test content 123</div>

<div id="test2">Test Content 456</div>

<div id="test3">Test Content 789</div>
```

Comment: You're Awesome!!

Comment: Thanks :) Happy to help